# BS4 webscraping to CSV file, think i am grabbing too may rows ('tr')s

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

My webscrape code grabs more rows of data than i need. I would like to grab rows per player, looks like these "tr" all include:-

```
<tr class="diff-row evTabRow bc"
```

Also the TD data that i want to grab is the:-
     data-odig=
from below list of table data:-

```
<td class="bc bs o" data-bk="B3" data-odig="9" data-o="8" data-hcap="" data-fodds="9.0" data-ew-denom="4" data-ew-places="5" xpath="1"><p>9</p></td>
```

the code is picking up the
     data-o=
td which is problematic for me as is sometimes expressed as a fraction.

Any advice appreciated

I am new to coding, python my first try.
My code has been written mainly from what i have picked up from youtube and copied others trying to fit my needs. I have tried to edit to be specific about the type of table rows and data to include but just cannot find an answer that works (numerous syntax errors). I suspect i have a line or two that is not doing anything also.

```
url = 'https://www.oddschecker.com/golf/the-masters/2020-us-masters/winner'

r = requests.get(url,headers = header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
table = soup.findAll("table")[1]

rows_list = []

for rows in table.findAll('tr'):
    cell_list = []
    for cell in rows.findAll('td'):
        text=cell.text
        cell_list.append(text)
    rows_list.append(cell_list)
```

Comment: Thanks martineau - you have solved my issue with table rows.

Comment: how do i get the data-odig= value         from the following data i would want to retrieve the value 9 from this example -                      
 <td class="bc bs o" data-bk="B3" data-odig="9" data-o="8" data-hcap="" data-fodds="9.0" data-ew-denom="4" data-ew-places="5" xpath="1"><p>9</p></td>

Answer (score 1):

`find()` and `findAll()/find_all()` can get other arguments to filter results

```
findAll('tr', {'class': 'diff-row evTabRow bc'})
```

or

```
findAll('tr', class_='diff-row evTabRow bc')
```

You can use `True` if attribute has to exists but it may have different values

```
findAll('td', {'data-o': True})
```

---

See more in documentation for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)